# deserialization of json array response in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

Can someone please help me with a script to deserialize the below json response. I will like to access the contained variables and their values

```
{  
  "results":[  
  {  
     "bulkId":"80664c0c-e1ca-414d-806a-5caf146463df",
     "messageId":"bcfb828b-7df9-4e7b-8715-f34f5c61271a",
     "to":"41793026731",
     "sentAt":"2015-02-12T09:51:43.123+0100",
     "doneAt":"2015-02-12T09:51:43.127+0100",
     "smsCount":1,
     "mccMnc": "22801",
     "price":{  
        "pricePerMessage":0.01,
        "currency":"EUR"
     },
     "callbackData": "User defined data.",
     "status":{  
        "groupId":3,
        "groupName":"DELIVERED",
        "id":5,
        "name":"DELIVERED_TO_HANDSET",
        "description":"Message delivered to handset"
     },
     "error":{  
        "groupId":0,
        "groupName":"OK",
        "id":0,
        "name":"NO_ERROR",
        "description":"No Error",
        "permanent":false
     }
  },
  {  
     "bulkId":"08fe4407-c48f-4d4b-a2f4-9ff583c985b8",
     "messageId":"12db39c3-7822-4e72-a3ec-c87442c0ffc5",
     "to":"41793026727",
     "sentAt":"2015-02-12T09:50:22.221+0100",
     "doneAt":"2015-02-12T09:50:22.232+0100",
     "smsCount":1,
     "mccMnc": "22801",
     "price":{  
        "pricePerMessage":0.01,
        "currency":"EUR"
     },
     "callbackData": "reset_password",
     "status":{  
        "groupId":3,
        "groupName":"DELIVERED",
        "id":5,
        "name":"DELIVERED_TO_HANDSET",
        "description":"Message delivered to handset"
     },
     "error":{  
        "groupId":0,
        "groupName":"OK",
        "id":0,
        "name":"NO_ERROR",
        "description":"No Error",
             "permanent":false
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

This is the new code
     <%@ Page Language="VB" Debug = "true"%>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"%>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.net.mail"%>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data"%>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.http" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace= "System.Web" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace ="System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.text" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
     <%@ Import namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="RestSharp" %>
     <%@ Import namespace= "System.Collections.Generic" %>
     <%@ Import namespace ="System.Linq" %>
     <%@ Import namespace ="Newtonsoft.Json.Linq" %>

```
 <SCRIPT language="vb" runat="server">
 ''' <summary>
 ''' JSON Serialization and Deserialization Assistant Class
 ''' </summary>
```

Public Class Price

```
     Public Property pricePerMessage As Double
     Public Property currency As String
 End Class

 Public Class Status
     Public Property groupId As Integer
     Public Property groupName As String
     Public Property id As Integer
     Public Property name As String
     Public Property description As String
 End Class

 Public Class ErrorModel
     Public Property groupId As Integer
     Public Property groupName As String
     Public Property id As Integer
     Public Property name As String
     Public Property description As String
     Public Property permanent As Boolean
 End Class

 Public Class Result
     Public Property bulkId As String
     Public Property messageId As String
     Public Property to As String
     Public Property sentAt As DateTime
     Public Property doneAt As DateTime
     Public Property smsCount As Integer
     Public Property mccMnc As String
     Public Property price As Price
     Public Property callbackData As String
     Public Property status As Status
     Public Property error As ErrorModel
 End Class

 Public Class Response
  Public Property results As Result()
 End Class

 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 Dim json  = "{""results"":   [{""bulkId"":""1454508683222745512"",""messageId"":""fbaa8cbd-62a2-4cdd-92a3-ebc962586356"",""to"":""2348166734353"",""sentAt"":""2016-02-03T14:11:24.509+0000"",""doneAt"":""2016-02-05T14:11:30.017+0000"",""smsCount"":1,""price"":{""pricePerMessage"":1.2500000000,""currency"":""NGN""},""status"":{""groupId"":4,""groupName"":""EXPIRED"",""id"":15,""name"":""EXPIRED_EXPIRED"",""description"":""Message expired""},""error"":{""groupId"":1,""groupName"":""HANDSET_ERRORS"",""id"":27,""name"":""EC_ABSENT_SUBSCRIBER"",""description"":""Absent Subscriber"",""permanent"":false}}]}"

  Dim response As Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Response)(json);

 Dim bulkId As String = response.Results(0).bulkId
    Response.Write(bulkId)
 End Sub
 </SCRIPT>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form runat="server">

 </form>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like [this](http://jsonutils.com/) to generate the classes you would need for the deserialization.

These are the classes that were generated from the JSON in your post

```
Public Class Price
    Public Property pricePerMessage As Double
    Public Property currency As String
End Class

Public Class Status
    Public Property groupId As Integer
    Public Property groupName As String
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property description As String
End Class

Public Class ErrorModel
    Public Property groupId As Integer
    Public Property groupName As String
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property permanent As Boolean
End Class

Public Class Result
    Public Property bulkId As String
    Public Property messageId As String
    Public Property to As String
    Public Property sentAt As DateTime
    Public Property doneAt As DateTime
    Public Property smsCount As Integer
    Public Property mccMnc As String
    Public Property price As Price
    Public Property callbackData As String
    Public Property status As Status
    Public Property error As ErrorModel
End Class

Public Class Response
    Public Property results As Result()
End Class
```

With the classes you can then use a library like [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which can be used to deserialize and access the properties of the JSON using strongly typed classes.

assuming the data is stored in a variable `json`

```
Dim response As Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Response)(json);

Dim bulkId As String = response.Results(0).bulkId
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. it came up with this error:  highlighting line 35.Compiler Error Message: BC30183: Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

Source Error:


Line 33: End Class
Line 34: 
Line 35: Public Class Error

Comment: Looks like naming conflict with a reserved keyword. I updated the class and property. See if it works now

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. It comes up with another error message "Keyword not valid as an valid identifier" on page 46. highlighting " Public Property to As String" i tried changing variable name "to" to "to1" but the error persists. I have added the complete test code as seen above. Kindly advice

Comment: Assign a JsonProperty Attribute on the offending property in this case `to` and change the name of the property to something that wont conflict with vb syntax

Comment: please how do i do that ? Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'Price' is not defined.

Comment: You commented out the price class in the updated code

Comment: yes. i  noticed and corrected that but its showing now "Public Property error As ErrorModel"